# LexikJWTAuthentificationBundle {"code":401,"message":"Bad credentials"}

Tags: authentication, jwt

i want to integrate jwtauthentificationbundle with fosuserbundle so i can generate a token for my REST APi ,but when i test it with postman :
post http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login_check 
this is my security.yml:

security:
       encoders:
            FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

```
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username


firewalls:

    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false


    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            username_parameter: username
            password_parameter: password
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator


    main:
        anonymous: ~


access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

and this is my routing.yml:

```
app:
resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
type: annotation

app_api:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/Api'
    type: annotation
```

api_login_check:
        path: /api/login_check

NelmioApiDocBundle:
        resource: "@NelmioApiDocBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        prefix:   /api/doc

fos_user:
        resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

any help ??

Comment: i found the anwser is whent i test it with postman ,i must send data with 
headers :content-type  application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to specify your provider on the login firewall ?
It give something like this for mine :

```
   firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        provider: fos_userbundle
        form_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            provider: main
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false
```

Comment: YES ,i found the solution;first like you said : add the provider in the lofin firewall and second i make he request header in postman with content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. itworks fine ! thanks .